# Helix about an axis

Tags: matlab, curve, helix

I have a query with regards to creating a helix about an axis. In general we create a helix about a vertical axis using the below code

```
t = 0:pi/50:20*pi;
st = sin(t);
ct = cos(t);
plot3(st,ct,t)
```

Is it possible to create a helix around a curve as shown in below image? If yes, can you please let me know how can i implement this in the code?

Helix about a curve - The Image is found below

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not so much of Matlab problem but more that of a proper formulation of the mathematical problem. Define a set of global axes (fixed), another one local to the curve supporting the helix and then the parameterization of the helix in the local system. Having that, project the parameterization in the global axes and you'll be set. I'd start with a 2D example first (which is equivalent to a 3D case with a planar supporting curve) to get the feel of it.